# Which ProjectReactor Processor to choose?

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

What is the most appropriate ProjectReactor `Processor` to use with the following use case:

Say the core function of the game service has 10 rest calls. After each of those call's purpose/activity is complete, we need to update the users score. There's a separate User Score service that tracks each users score. Most importantly, we want the User Score service calls to be asynchronous and not block the response to the 10 calls supporting the game. In other words, only after (or asynchronously) the core rest controller methods to return their data to the caller, should the updates to the User Score service happen.

The rest controller is built using Spring Webflux, and all calls require network resources (database or other service calls), so are subscribed on the elastic scheduler.  As such, the events will be produced from different threads, thus this is a multi-threaded source.

Consuming the events from the Process's stream should be asynchronous as well, with perhaps a way to limit the concurrent requests so that we can prioritize the response to the 10 main calls, instead of updating scores.

Comment: What about starting brand new stream updating user score, as a side effect? I mean something like `controllerFlux.doOnComplete(()-> updateservice.update().subscribe())`. Resources limiting can be achieved by creating and assigning different, custom size schedulers for controllerFlux and updateFlux, e.g. `Schedulers.newElastic(...)`.

Comment: please post a code example instead of describing how things are.

Comment: From what you've described, I'm not convinced you need a specific processor at all.

Comment: @MichaelBerry What do you suggest instead?